# Django: how to get a manager with all objects for a model?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a Django model with a weird Manager definition in one of my apps:

```
# this code cannot be altered:
class WeirdManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(WeirdManager, self).get_query_set().none()

class HasWeirdManager(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()

    objects = WeirdManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager() # may or may not exist
```

`all_objects` may or may not exist; in any case I cannot know it exists generally. How do I get a reference to an "unspoiled" `models.Manager` for this type?

```
# this is my own code:
this_is_the_question(HasWeirdManager).get(pk=1)

# another example:
this_is_the_question(HasWeirdManager).update({'value': 10})
```

I.e., in the above, what is the value of `this_is_the_question`?

Answer (score 3):

That was quick:

The answer is `HasWeirdManager._base_manager`